# Falha de impressao com impressora Zebra GC420T

Tags: java

Bom dia, estou com um pequeno problema ao imprimir etiquetas em uma impressora Zebra GC420T a partir de uma Java Viewer. O fato é que a impressão sai correta, mas a impressora continua liberando o rolo de papel depois e sai mais uma 5 etiquetas em branco. A etiqueta foi feita com Jasper Report. O único problema é esse de sair mais papel que o necessário. Já pesquisei mas não encontrei nada referente. Alguém já teve esse problema, ou tem uma sugestão de o que pode ser a causa.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: acredito que o problema de sair papel após a impressão, esteja diretamente ligada com o tamanho da impressão
Verifique tamanho impresso x tamanho da etiqueta.

Comment: Já andei ollhando isso, mas vou verificar melhor. Na configuração de pagina do jasper está correto, mas quando abro as propriedades do arquivo tem um valor diferente para a largura e altura.

Comment: Provavelmente seja esse o problema

Comment: Infelizmente não é isso. tenho no jasper 10x5 cm em retrato. e é o que a impressora deve receber. Não pode ser alguma configuração no jasper viewer que tenha que ser setada?

Comment: A impressora Zebra está como padrão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já tive o mesmo problema utilizando relatórios Jasper, verifique se não existe espaço em branco no fim da etiqueta e tente diminuir o tamanho da band. No meu caso resolveu. Boa sorte!

Comment: Obrigado Moslite. Vou verificar isso.

Comment: minha etiqueta é 10x5 cm. E descobri que mesmo setando isso no page format do jasper ele está jogando 10.8x29.7 cm no jasper viewer. verifiquei a influencia da margens mas não surtiu efeito. Na verdade se ajusta para 9,984x4,974 cm com margens de 0,706 cm. Descobri o problema só falta descobrir a solução.